# How to upload image to mysql with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I try to upload image to mysql table with node.js. But there is no result. The query works fine when I try to upload userName and lastName for example, but it doesn't work when I try to upload image.

Here is my sql query:

```
const sql = `INSERT INTO user(firstName, lastName, image) VALUES ('${firstName}', '${lastName}', '${image}')`
```

Here are my consts:

```
const firstName = req.body.firstName
const lastName = req.body.lastName
const image = await sharp(req.file.buffer).resize({width: 250, height: 250}).png().toBuffer()
```

I expect the data to be stored in the table

Comment: You could use a base64 string but storing images at database is a bad practice

Comment: @vitomadio this is incorrect, you can store a file in a blob field, Whether you should, that's a different question.

Comment: @Shadow I know that this is a bad practice. But in my case it should be stored this way. I have an image field (binary) in my db and I pass a binary image in the sql query. But there is no result ...

Comment: Passing binary data with string interpolation is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the table definition as well, It would be helpful too, But I really don't understand why you are storing images in the database instead of a directory, In my whole 8 years of experience, I never heard like that.

pardon me, but if images can get quite large greater than 1 MB, so storing images in a database can potentially put unnecessary load on your database and the network between your database and your web server if they're on different hosts.

General practice is to store images in directories on the file system and store references to the images in the database. e.g. path to the image,the image name, etc.. Or alternatively, you may even store images on a content delivery network (CDN) or numerous hosts across some great expanse of physical territory, and store references to access those resources in the database.

Comment: I have firstName (varchar(225)), lastName(varchar(225)), image(binary). The goal is to store binary images in db. This is test work. So, I try to pass binary image to the sql query.

Comment: Not much, hands on the MySQL try to change the datatype if image field with `LONGBLOB NOT NULL`.